# Thread execution time in C/Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, pthreads

Wandering if I can measure actual time or cpu ticks taken by a particular thread.

```
pthreadcreate(.........);
//
//
pthreadjoin(.......);
```

I am running with 3 threads.

One master thread is calling the rest two threads.
I want to measure the execution time for a called thread.

what should I use in linux environment ?

Comment: Tried this one..? http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/201513/how-to-get-a-threads-execution-time

Comment: Thank you Hiren,

Looking for more tuned result, in microsecond..

Comment: Try `clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, ...)` at thread entry/exit (you can use a wrapper function for your `pthread_create` entrypoint to avoid changing multiple thread functions.

Comment: this is a process level measurement.
I dont think it will give with proper clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do one thing

In thread function at start up make a log using printk. You can separate it with different thread printing with it thread_t variable or thread index

and at end of that thread function put another log like that.

So in `dmesg`

will shows the log with `timestamp`

so you can differentiate end log time with start log time.

I know this is not more practical way of doing this but just for debugging purpose you can do this without much effort.

Comment: looks great !!
I already have done with the same approach.
further looking for a better approach/clarity !!

Comment: Why printk? printk is used in kernel space. And there is no pthread. There is kthread and which is far different than pthread. dmesg will work then. Try collecting the time at the moment the thrad starts and ends may give useful results. Because programs may never use pthread_join at all if they don't need it. We often need threads which exist as long as the program.

Comment: @rr_ovi yea good catch here op wants in kernel space so no pthread.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a more accurate result you can use tick counters :

```
#ifndef TIMING_H
#define TIMING_H

/*
 * -- Init timing library with timing_init();
 * -- get timestamp :
 *  tick_t t;
 *  GET_TICK(t);
 * -- get delay between two timestamps in microseconds :
 *  TIMING_DELAY(t1, t2);
 */

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifndef min
#define min(a,b) \
    ({__typeof__ ((a)) _a = (a); \
      __typeof__ ((b)) _b = (b); \
      _a < _b ? _a : _b; })
#endif

typedef union u_tick
{
  uint64_t tick;

  struct
  {
    uint32_t low;
    uint32_t high;
  }
  sub;
} tick_t;

static double scale_time = 0.0;
static unsigned long long residual = 0;

#if defined(__i386__) || defined(__pentium__) || defined(__pentiumpro__) || defined(__i586__) || defined(__i686__) || defined(__k6__) || defined(__k7__) || defined(__x86_64__)
#  define GET_TICK(t) __asm__ volatile("rdtsc" : "=a" ((t).sub.low), "=d" ((t).sub.high))
#else
#  error "Unsupported processor"
#endif

#define TICK_RAW_DIFF(t1, t2) ((t2).tick - (t1).tick)
#define TICK_DIFF(t1, t2) (TICK_RAW_DIFF(t1, t2) - residual)
#define TIMING_DELAY(t1, t2) tick2usec(TICK_DIFF(t1, t2))

void timing_init(void)
{
  static tick_t t1, t2;
  int i;

  residual = (unsigned long long)1 << 63;

  for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
      GET_TICK(t1);
      GET_TICK(t2);
      residual = min(residual, TICK_RAW_DIFF(t1, t2));
    }

  {
    struct timeval tv1,tv2;

    GET_TICK(t1);
    gettimeofday(&tv1,0);
    usleep(500000);
    GET_TICK(t2);
    gettimeofday(&tv2,0);
    scale_time = ((tv2.tv_sec*1e6 + tv2.tv_usec) -
         (tv1.tv_sec*1e6 + tv1.tv_usec)) / 
      (double)(TICK_DIFF(t1, t2));
  }
}

double tick2usec(long long t)
{
  return (double)(t)*scale_time;
}

#endif /* TIMING_H */
```